# Creating a duplicate database on same server Oracle 11g

Tags: php, codeigniter, oracle11g

Here is the picture of my layout -
I have a php source code of a software and an Oracle 11g DB which is connected to this source code. I am planning to use this software as a Saas for my clients and all of this code is to be run on my server.

I want my clients to have a separate setup for their software, therefore I need to copy this source code for  each client to a new folder, but the question is how can I duplicate an Oracle 11g schema on the same server.

What is the best way to go about it?

Comment: Check link,you will get idea,http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/11g/duplicate-database-using-rman-11gr2.php

Comment: Thanks very much! I found interesting cloning possibility from that document!

Comment: Are you going to do it automatically in code or manually? I am keeping one common schema for all my clients and using with table prefix set in CI. So I didn't have to duplicate schema but only need to create additional set of tables for each user.

Comment: I was thinking of doing it manually, although in the future if there will be many clients, I would prefer to have automatic duplication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer to this problem.

Export the schema you want to use.
Create a new user.
Grant the new user permissions and then import the schema.